# iNotify how to detect move-out

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, inotify

Hi there I am using iNotify to detect changes in a directory. The flags I am using are `IN_CLOSE_WRITE | IN_MOVED_FROM | IN_MOVED_TO | IN_CREATE`

I am trying to differentiate between a `IN_MOVED_FROM` when renaming, and the `IN_MOVED_FROM` when a file is moved out of the folder.

- I thought to check if the `cookie` field is not 0 when user moved the file out. As I thought `cookie` was only for rename procedure. However even when I move the file out of the directory it still has a cookie.
- I also though to check for `IN_MODIFY` as I was hoping that would be there on rename but not on move, but its not there for either.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to detect if it was just "moved-out" or it is the "renamed-from-oldfilename"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for the `IN_MOVED_FROM` event and a following `IN_MOVED_TO` event. If the cookie is the same, the file has been renamed in the same folder. If you don't receive a `IN_MOVED_TO` event with the same cookie, the file has been moved outside of the watched folder.

Comment: Thanks @hek2! So but my problem is the IN_MOVED_TO is not coming in the same buffer, so when I get IN_MOVED_FROM should I wait like a few milliseconds, and then if no IN_MOVED_TO then declare it a move?

Comment: Basically renaming a file is an atomic operation, regardless of if it happens in the same folder or not. I expect the `IN_MOVED_TO` occur immediately after that. I need to reproduce this to give you something reliable.

Comment: Thanks @hek2mgl! So if I get a `IN_MOVED_TO` I'll check a if a pervious `IN_MOVED_FROM` with same cookie happend before that, if it didn't then I declare that as item was moved into the folder. So this is assumption that if renamed, then `IN_MOVED_FROM` always happens first. And if `IN_MOVED_FROM` happens first, I shouldnt assume right away its a moved out of the folder, but I should check the same buffer if there is a `IN_MOVED_TO` after that point with same cookie, if it is in the same buffer and after the `IN_MOVED_FROM` then I can declare that moved from. Just thinking out loud here :)Thx!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking too. If you mean the *same* buffer you mean events related to the same `wd`?

Comment: Oh yes thanks for that reminder `wd` is a big thing. Especially if I look for a previous `IN_MOVED_FROM` and it's of a different `wd` then we can declare that was due to it being moved from there (in the case the user is watching two paths and the user moved the item from first path to 2nd path). Thanks very much for this discussion! I'll test later this week and report back! :)

Comment: Hey @hek2 I hooked it up and from my testing so far our assumptions are holding true! :) Thank you! :)

Comment: Cool! :) Don't hesitate to post a short example as an answer to your own question (if you want). It would be a very good reference for others (including me :) )

Answer (score 1):

I applied the logic mention by @hek2mgl and its working so big thanks to him. This is js-ctypes code:

```
while (true) {
    let length = ostypes.API('read')(fd, buf, count);

    length = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(length));

    if (length == -1) {
        throw new Error({
            name: 'os-api-error',
            message: 'Failed to read during poll',
            uniEerrno: ctypes.errno
        });
    } else if (!length==0) {
        // then its > 0 as its not -1
        // something happend, read struct
        let FSChanges = [];
        var i = 0;
        var numElementsRead = 0;

        length = parseInt(cutils.jscGetDeepest(length));
        var _cache_aRenamed_local = {}; // local means per buffer
        do {
            let iHoisted = i;
            numElementsRead++;
            var casted = ctypes.cast(buf.addressOfElement(iHoisted), ostypes.TYPE.inotify_event.ptr).contents;

            var fileName = casted.addressOfField('name').contents.readString();
            var mask = casted.addressOfField('mask').contents;
            var len = casted.addressOfField('len').contents;
            var cookie = cutils.jscGetDeepest(casted.addressOfField('cookie').contents)
            var wd = casted.addressOfField('wd').contents;

            var aEvent = convertFlagsToAEventStr(mask);



            if (aEvent == 'renamed-to') {
                if (cookie in _cache_aRenamed_local) { // assuming that renamed-from must happen before rename-to otherwise its a added
                    if (_cache_aRenamed_local[cookie].aExtra.aOSPath_parentDir_identifier == wd) { // aOSPath_parentDir_identifier is a wd if its different then the current wd then it was added/removed from that watched dir
                        var rezObj = {
                            aFileName: fileName,
                            aEvent: 'renamed',
                            aExtra: {
                                nixInotifyFlags: mask, // i should pass this, as if user did modify the flags, they might want to figure out what exactly changed
                                aOSPath_parentDir_identifier: wd,
                                aOld: {
                                    aFileName: _cache_aRenamed_local[cookie].aFileName,
                                    aExtra: {
                                        nixInotifyFlags: _cache_aRenamed_local[cookie].aExtra.nixInotifyFlags
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        FSChanges.push(rezObj);
                    } else {
                        // the one in cache was removed from its parent folder, this one here was added to parent folder. so this is detect as file moved from one watched dir to another watched dir
                        if (_cache_aRenamed_local[cookie].aFileName != fileName) {
                            console.error('whaaaaa wd\'s are differnt and got renamed-to so names should be same');
                            _cache_aRenamed_local[cookie].aEvent = 'haaa names are different?? im just going to say REMOVED as a guess i have never encoutnered this situation yet and i dont think we ever should';
                            FSChanges.push(_cache_aRenamed_local[cookie]);
                        } else {
                            _cache_aRenamed_local[cookie].aEvent = 'removed';
                            FSChanges.push(_cache_aRenamed_local[cookie]);
                        }
                    }
                    delete _cache_aRenamed_local[cookie];
                } else {
                    var rezObj = {
                        aFileName: fileName,
                        aEvent: 'added',
                        aExtra: {
                            aOSPath_parentDir_identifier: wd
                        }
                    }
                    FSChanges.push(rezObj);
                }
            } else if (aEvent == 'renamed-from') {
                var rezObj = {
                    aFileName: fileName,
                    aEvent: aEvent,
                    aExtra: {
                        aOSPath_parentDir_identifier: wd
                    }
                }
                _cache_aRenamed_local[cookie] = rezObj;
            } else {
                var rezObj = {
                    aFileName: fileName,
                    aEvent: aEvent,
                    aExtra: {
                        aOSPath_parentDir_identifier: wd
                    }
                }
                FSChanges.push(rezObj);
            }

            if (len == 0) {
                break;
            };
            i += nixStuff.sizeField0 + nixStuff.sizeField1 + nixStuff.sizeField2 + nixStuff.sizeField3 + parseInt(len);
        } while (i < length);
        for (var cookieLeft in _cache_aRenamed_local) {
            // whatever is left in _cache_aRenamed_local is `removed` things
            _cache_aRenamed_local[cookieLeft].aEvent = 'removed';
            FSChanges.push(rezObj);
        }
        console.error('loop ended:', 'numElementsRead:', numElementsRead);

        if (FSChanges.length > 0) {
            return FSChanges;
        } // else dont return and continue loop
    }
}
```

I use this function to convert the flags to a string of like `renamed-from` or `renamed-to`

```
function convertFlagsToAEventStr(flags) {
    var default_flags = {
        IN_CLOSE_WRITE: 'contents-modified',
        IN_MOVED_TO: 'renamed-to', // can also be a added
        IN_DELETE: 'removed',
        IN_MOVED_FROM: 'renamed-from', // can also be a removed
        IN_CREATE: 'added'
    };


    for (var f in default_flags) {
        if (flags & ostypes.CONST[f]) {
            return default_flags[f];
        }
    }
    return 'UNKNOWN FLAG';
}
```